# Mysql Query with SUM and WHERE does not work

Tags: mysql, sql

```
include 'conn.php';

$page = isset($_POST['page']) ? intval($_POST['page']) : 1;
$rows = isset($_POST['rows']) ? intval($_POST['rows']) : 10;
$sort = isset($_POST['sort']) ? strval($_POST['sort']) : 'saleid';
$order = isset($_POST['order']) ? strval($_POST['order']) : 'desc';

$orderno = isset($_POST['orderno']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['orderno']) : ''; 

$offset = ($page-1)*$rows;
$result = array();

$where = "orderno like '$orderno%'"; 
$rs = mysql_query("select count(*) from tblsales where " . $where); 
$row = mysql_fetch_row($rs);
$result["total"] = $row[0];
$rs = mysql_query("select *, sum(price+shipping+paypalfee+storefee) as totalcost from tblsales group by orderno where " . $where . " order by $sort $order limit $offset,$rows");

$items = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($rs)){
    array_push($items, $row);
}
$result["rows"] = $items;

echo json_encode($result);
```

**Could you please change this query so that it returns all records in table while using WHERE clause so that I could search a particular record if needed. At the moment it does not return anything:**

```
  select *, sum(price+shipping+paypalfee+storefee) as totalcost
  from tblsales 
  group by orderno 
  where " . $where . " 
  order by $sort $order 
  limit $offset,$rows
```

Comment: I changed WHERE to HAVING and it works... WOW

Comment: Careful! You're misusing MySQL's GROUP BY extension. The only columns in your result set that have a predictable values are `orderno` and the sum. The rest of the values won't be predictable. Read this. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: @BubbaYakoza . . . You could also fix it by putting the `where` before the `group by`, where it belongs.

Comment: @BubbaYakoza You're using a long-since deprecated API. See mysqli_/PDO and, crucially, prepared statements!!

Comment: @GordonLinoff How could I round totalcost?

Comment: @BubbaYakoza . . . By using `round()`, `format()`, or converting to a decimal type.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I get error in using round ... could you please write the syntax

Comment: No, your query has other problems such as using `group by` with `select *`.  You can ask another question with sample data and desired results if you want to get the best results out.  As for this question, your use of the `having` clause or moving the `where` clause answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select *,sum(totalcost) 
FROM (select *, price+shipping+paypalfee+storefee as totalcost from tblsales) x
group by orderno 
where " . $where . " 
order by $sort $order 
limit $offset,$rows
```